# Synchronize one table between MySQL database(s)

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds

We have the requirement to synchronize the data in a table across multiple MySQL databases. One of the databases would be the source, and all others need to have the synchronized data for one of the tables.

We have multiple databases used in microservice architecture, and they all need to have a local copy of a specific table in their database, and not the entire database itself, hence read replica or multi-AZ configuration is not the solution.

Database: MySQL hosted on AWS RDS

Is there any managed service by AWS or another vendor that can be used to accomplish this? Or do we have to write a custom script to do that?

Comment: Did you find best way to do this?

Comment: @Md.MahmudHasan, unfortunately, nothing except writing a custom script to do this. Please let me know if you find a managed service to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to either isolate the table in one database and replicate that database or write a custom script.

If I were writing a custom script I would look at the binlog functionality. Here are some helpful links:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlbinlog.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html (at the bottom).

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple MySQL replication. But you have to replicate the whole database. So create a MySQL database in AWS and enable Multi-AZ replication and activate the automatic snapshots.

The A-Z Replication is synchronous. When you use a "Read replica" it's asynchronous. So if you have very important data you should enable Multi-AZ replication.

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/multi-az/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stony, but we are not looking for a read replica. We have multiple databases used in microservice architecture, and they all need to have a local copy of a specific table in their database, and not the entire database.

Comment: You should read my comment again ;) AZ Replication is no Read replica.

Comment: My comment got saved by mistake. Just edited it and provided more context on the requirement. Editing the question as well.

Comment: If you really try to replicate only one table you should take a look at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table

but that it's not working on AWS. Then you have to build your cluster on your own and that is not really easy.

Comment: Then the only option would be to write custom code to replicate data in the table amongst multiple databases. Thanks for your help, but will look forward to any other answers on this.

Comment: How many different databases does this table need to be replicated to? Across AZs or regions? Synchronous or asynchronous?